# Open several terminals with one click

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((n=0;n<3;n++))
do
gnome-terminal
done
```

This is the code for opening three terminals. I have asset it graphical in Ubuntu desktop. When I click the icon, only one terminal opens, when I close the terminal another opens, this goes on to three. But when I run the script in the terminal itself, all three terminals open simultaneously. This is what I'm after, having my icon on the desktop open them up simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..3}; do
    gnome-terminal &
done
```

`&` run the command in the background. (silently `fork()`)